# How to make chroot work for vsftp when client accesses ftp from a Windows or Mac machine?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, filezilla

I setup vsftp on a server with chroot enabled so that users cannot get out of their home directory.

This works when the client accesses the ftp server from a Linux machine.

But when a client accesses the ftp server from a Windows or Mac machine, they can see directories outside of their home directory.

If I access the ftp server with Filezilla on Linux, the home directory appears as the root directory, but if I access it with Filezilla on Windows, I can see the actual directory and can navigate all the way up to the root directory and from there explore the whole filesystem.

Why does this happen?

Comment: What FTP clients, on Windows/Mac, are you using?  If browser-based ones, could those clients have _cached_ the view of the server filesystem they are showing you?

Comment: The same ftp client is used on Linux, Mac, and Windows, it's in the description. It looks like this happens because it defaults to ftp if it can't connect through sftp, but it doesn't do this on Linux.